# Combing two projects into a single project - Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have two projects and I want to combine this project into a single project folder. Project A is my main project and I want to use Project B inside project A, so how can I merge this two project into one project for me to compile it into a single folder? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

1. In Eclipse, right click on Project A, and go to **Properties**.
2. Go to the **Java Build Path** section.
3. Navigate to the **Projects** tab and add Project B from there.

Project A will now be able to reference Project B's classes during editing.